# error: unable to locate the device's timestamp on the device while profiling an iOS app on xcode time profiler instruments

Tags: xcode-instruments

I am trying to profile my iOS app, but everytime i profile it, the instruments(time profiler to be specific) it shows the

> **error: unable to locate the device's timestamp**

. I am unable to find the reason why this might be happening. Any pointers?

The xcode version is 9.2 and my iPAD is on ios version-12.0.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it's happening is that Xcode 9.2 does not support versions of iOS later than iOS 11.2, including iOS 12. You have two options: use Xcode 10 to profile on your iPad or profile your app on a device running iOS 11.