# Do you know why the Instrument is offline?

Tags: xcode, instruments, xcode-instruments

Test device is visible in Xcode. But Measuring instruments display offline. I have tried to reboot both the device and MacBook, but they still appear offline.

If I don't try to build it, it will be not displayed on the measuring instrument???????

Xcode version 9.2(9C40b) / OS X version 10.12.6

[image: xcode and Instruments]

Comment: You need Xcode 10.1 to profile on a device running iOS 12.1. See the following question: [error: unable to locate the device's timestamp on the device while profiling an iOS app on xcode time profiler instruments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53533187/error-unable-to-locate-the-devices-timestamp-on-the-device-while-profiling-an/53546103#53546103)

Comment: If you're running the latest Xcode and still facing the issue, try restart your device.